# Is there a way to switch accounts in Google analytics?

Tags: account-management, google-analytics, login

I have several Google accounts. In products like Gmail or Calendar I see my address on the top right corner and when I click on it I can switch to other accounts I'm logged in with. But in Google analytics there's no such a thing. It seems Google analytics just picks the default account and shows me that. Is there a way to switch accounts in Google analytics without logging out from the other accounts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Analytics, among some other Google products, does not currently support account switching.

Comment: Is this is still actual today - after 2+ years from original post?

Comment: @Sevenate Yes, you still can't switch accounts. It's really lame.

Answer (score 1):

As of **May 2018**, you can switch between Google accounts by clicking account icon (in top right corner of Google Analytics page):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use the profiles feature of chrome. Create two profiles, one for each gmail id. When ever you try to change a profile, the new profile will open in a new chrome window where you will be logged in as that profile.

The Google answer page for creating a profile still seems to show the old method where you had to create profile directory manually. Here's an alternate with a video.
http://www.skipser.com/500